# How to get working directory in node-webkit

Tags: working-directory, node-webkit

I've got a simple program that can be run from command line.
This program is for live preview of markdown files.
When i'm packaging the app with

```
cat $NW/nw marknow.nw > marknow
```

and running from different location:

```
./build/marknow ../relative/path/to/file.md
```

I can't get current working directory.

```
process.cwd()
```

is returning /tmp/something???

How can I get working directory in node-webkit? Directory from which `./build/marknow ../relative/path/to/file.md` was called.

Comment: process.cwd() is returning exactly what I'm looking for, absolute path, maybe that was an older version of node-webkit?

Comment: @Maslow: In that case I think maybe you were not looking for cwd in the traditional meaning of the term - which is the directory where the process was started by the user (which is usually different from the directory where the app is installed). Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `cwd` is getting 2 different meanings:

1. directory where the app lives
2. directory where the user launch the app from

In shell scripting [I can see the 2nd meaning applied](http://www.linfo.org/current_directory.html), but the node-webkit community 
[seems to be using the 1st](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/264)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are looking for the 2nd: the path where the user was when calling to your app.

After some tests I finally found a way that works for me:

`process.env.PWD`

Comment: process.env.PWD does not seem to be available when you build your project to an executable.

Comment: @squaretone: Did you observe this in a windows build? I did a build for mac where the process.env.PWD did contain the path of the directory I was in when I launched the app.

Comment: I don't recall. I've been developing on both but primarily building on Windows.

Answer (score 14):

Another option you could try if the cwd doesn't seem to work is getting the execution directory with something like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var execPath = path.dirname( process.execPath );
```

This should get you the execution directory of the exe. cwd gets the temp directory because of how node-webkit handles opening the files from a temp directory on each run.

Comment: path.dirname( process.execPath ) is pointing to ./build/ directory not to the current working directory.

Comment: to avoid scapes use `execPath.replace(/\\/g,"/");`

Answer (score 1):

As is pointed out in other answers, node-webkit starts up the node process with the wrong 'current working directory' (from a command line perspective anyway).

As is pointed out elsewhere, `process.env.PWD` in fact contains what we want (when the app is started from the command line). A simple workaround could then be to do the following in your index.html (or some other place that gets executed early):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(process.env.PWD) {
    process.chdir(process.env.PWD);
  }
</script>
```

Presto! Now process.cwd() returns the right thing.

Apparently, this trick only really works for apps that are started from the command line - but then again, it is probably only necessary when the app is launched from the command line.

There is a ticket for this issue, but it is [old and dusty](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/648)

Answer (score 1):

If all answer were failed, try this.

1. Create file "main.js" and copy this code.

   ```
   // get child_process module.
   var childproc = require('child_process');

   // start process using child_process
   //  with current path string
   // '__dirname' would be not only path
   //  of 'main.js' but also one of 'app.zip'
   //  because 'main.js' and 'app.zip' have same directory
   childproc.exec('nw app.zip ' + __dirname);
   ```
2. Add this code which you want to get current path

   ```
   // get 'nw.gui' module
   var gui = require('nw.gui');

   // get arguments that we passed
   var arr = gui.App.argv;

   // nw app.zip __dirname
   //            ^ argv[0]
   alert('current path: [' + arr[0] + ']');
   ```
3. Run "main.js" with node.js

I posted "How to get current directory(current path) using node-webkit".

http://hdnua.tistory.com/16

It gets executing zip file's directory.